# Display Parent page variable on Child page with template - wagtail/django

Tags: django, django-templates, wagtail

I  tried to look for solution but probably missed it, probably because I am unsure what exactly to ask.

I am new to Wagtail/Django.  How can I make variables from a parent page visible on child page?

I am trying to make a page that has Header, Content and Footer. I enclosed those inside `{% block name_of_section %}`. Now I have a child page (actually grandchild, but whatever) which template consists only of:

```
{% extends main_page.html %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags static wagtailuserbar %}

{% block content%}
   {{ page.photo }}
   {{ page.article }}
{% endblock %}
```

and the main page template (truncated of course):

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags static wagtailuserbar %}
htmlcode
{% block header %}some stuff here{% endblock %}
{% block content %}stuff to be replaced in child pages here{% endblock%}
{% block footer %}{{ page.address }} {{ page.links }} {{% endblock %}}
finishing html code here
```

Now the problem I am having is that when I load the child page, the header, content and footer display *almost* fine. The exceptions are those variables address and links from the footer. I assume it is because it gets passed to the child page still as `{{ page.address }}` and of course the child page has no address so the result is empty string.

My workaround was to (probably very wrongly) do this in the `models.py`:

```
def address(self):
    getattr(HomePage.objects.first(), 'address')
    return address
```

So when the home page is loaded, the template loads the variable and when the child page is loaded the template calls the method which (also probably in wrong way - but working) fetches the variable's value.

But it feels wrong. What is the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `address` is not really a field that belongs on the HomePage, but a global property of the site as a whole. If so, moving it to a [Site Settings model](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/settings.html) would be a better fit - that way you can easily make it available on all pages using the same base template.

More generally, if you have some global information to be displayed in the header / footer of all pages, but don't want to have to include the logic for retrieving that information in every page type, an [inclusion template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) is a good approach: write the retrieval logic in the function body of the template tag, then hand off to a template to render it. You then just need to insert that tag into your base template.

Comment: Ok, that sounds reasonable for the address. But what if it is something that is more prone to change and I would like to be easilly editable from the wagtail admin enviroment. Make it... I don't know... 'Joke of the week' on certain page and its children, editable by editors, not needing the site admins.
Or better example. Links to last 3 published articles are in the footer. Those can't be edited by hand every time you add one so the question stands I guess?

Comment: In that case I'd go for an inclusion template tag - have updated the answer with further details.